# Getting bank and heading angles from 6DOF IMU fusion

Tags: accelerometer, imu, gyro, sensor-fusion

I have an Arduino-based electronic musical instrument where I'd like to know the bank angle φ and heading angle ψ as shown in this diagram from Wikipedia [(Euler angle article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles):

[image]

The sensor fusion libraries that I've tried return Euler angles (roll, pitch, yaw), which are different from the angles shown in the diagram because roll and yaw are dependent on pitch. So, roll and yaw only represent bank and heading if pitch is close to zero. For example, if the pitch angle is zero, the bank angle φ is equivalent to "roll", but if the elevation angle vertical, the bank angle φ is equivalent to "yaw". The pitch angle (θ) is, I believe, the same in both systems.

My question: Is there a library that will return the bank and heading angles that I'm looking for, or could someone set me on a path to calculating them, perhaps from the quaternion? I've gotten a good approximation for the bank angle by integrating the gyro by itself and then periodically correcting it for gravity. However, it's a brute-force method and isn't perfect, because the gyro is sensitive to changes in both bank and heading. Unfortunately, my understanding of the math involved in all this is mostly nonexistent. From what I understand, this is all related to the frame of reference, but I'm not sure if it's just a matter of converting from one frame to another or if I need a fundamentally different type of fusion to get the angles of interest.